# Knockout.js getting element from json object and extracting into array

Tags: knockout-2.0

I have the following line:

```
 $.getJSON('@Url.Action("RegistrationShareClassReport", new { id = ViewBag.Id })', function (data) {
        viewModel.RegistrationShareClassReport(data);
    });
```

This basically returns data in json format with different elements. e.g.

```
id = "2",
name = "tj",
country = "GB"

id = "3",
name = "pj",
country = "IT"
```

What i want to is from that viewmodel populate an array of all the countries for each item. So i would need to loop through the viewmodel data and extract the countries from each.

I wanted to know i could achieve this in knockout.js?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Knockout mapping plugin (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) to map your json to your viewmodel.

Here's some code to get you started. Adjust it to your own needs:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.getJSON("/data.json", function (data) {

        var viewModel = {};

        var mapping = {
            "countries": {
                key: function (data) {
                    return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(data.name);
                }
            }
        };

        viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping);

        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    });
</script>
```

And then in HTML:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: $root">
    <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
</ul>
```